# Mediawiki editor reftoolbar missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mediawiki

For my projetc i installed mediawiki in my server, there everything works fine except cite(ref-tool bar). I am attaching the screenshot. Do we need any other js/css files to be included? Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia runs a lot of custom extensions to the MediaWiki software. Like on any MediaWiki installation, you can see a list of the installed extensions at [Special:Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aVersion). I believe that what you are looking for is [Extension:Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCite).