# Cite Option Not Showing using WikiEditor - WikiMedia

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have installed WIkiMedia 1.26.2. *WikiEditor* and *Cite* extension are included by default in the *extensions* directory. I tried to use them by adding these lines at bottom of `LocalSettings.php`

```
#load Wikieditor
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );

# Enables use of WikiEditor by default
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;

# load Cite
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
```

But still i'm not able to see it in editor. Cite button is not there.

When i see `Special:Version`, *Cite* and *WikiEditor* are there in the installed extensions.

I have the exact same problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649475/mediawiki-editor-reftoolbar-missing) and [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/How_to_install_RefToolbar_to_use_the_Cite_button_like_on_Wikipedia/reply)

Do i need to add/load any additional files?

Comment: Did you add `MediaWiki:RefToolbar.js` etc as per https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Citation_option_in_your_edit_toolbar#Getting_RefToolbar_with_the_.27cite.27_option_in_place: ?

Comment: How can i add it? I can browse it though, by appending `/MediaWiki:RefToolbar.js` to the domain name. Does this mean that this has been added?

Comment: Did you read the docs? And do you have a link to your wiki?